# How to make a forum like tag system for images in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to make a educational website using Django where anyone can create posts. Now in those posts I want to provide links to images in a tag so that it shows up in the post. For example something similar to the html img tag will do.

My Post creation view:

```py
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'display', 'category']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


def cat_on_all_pages(request):
    return {'cat': Category.objects.all()}
```

My html template for post creation (I use crispy forms here):

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Submit a Course{% endblock %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Submit or Edit a Course</legend>
                {{form|crispy}}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You can create a link that redirect to images for that post or you can add click event by javascript/jquery to show images on same page.

Comment: I have pretty much no knowledge of JavaScript so a bit of help would be appreciated. Also how am I supposed to create an link? If I put in an link in the post it does not seem to redirect. Instead it stays in Text form.